# Should I create an MVC model in this scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a Ruby on Rails 3.2 application and use formtastic and client-side-validations gems.

I have a user, and TableReservation with standard CRUD operations, the validations for which work with the aforementioned gems.

```
:user              :has_many   :table_reservations
:table_reservation :belongs_to :user
```

Now I need to add a 'search' form for the user to get details on his table_reservation which takes in `user.first_name`, `user.last_name` and `table_reservation.secret_token`. I need to add validations which will prevent a *normal* user from submitting the invalid form.

I was wondering if I should create a `TableReservationSearch` model to keep working with the formtastic, client_side_validations gems as before. At the same time, it feels like creating a model for this is unnecessary since it is not stored in the database. But then again this model need not inherit ActiveRecord but `include ActiveModel::Validations`, etc. I can also write a simple form and use a jQuery validations plugin or something similar.

So I am confused about when to create a model for such purposes and when not to!

What is the best way of approaching this subject?

Comment: Why do you have to validate the search form? If a query is entered that does not match any records tell the user so, if it does match something, display it. I don't see the necessity of validating and therefore I also don't think you need a model for this.

Comment: I don't want the user to be able to submit empty fields or an email with an invalid format.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for nested field validation. Please look to [this issue](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/49). Maybe this will help you. And there is no need to create a model for validating nested fields on the form. And on the validation code you can add an action too.